# Is this mysqli code using prepared statements safe against SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using prepared statements to prevent sql injection. I want to know if i am in right track or not to prevent sql injection using prepared statement. Below is an example html form.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="ff" id="ff">
<input type="text" name="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now when submitting the above form then i am using the following php code with prepared statements.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $query = "insert INTO table (input1,input2) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_REQUEST["input1"], $_REQUEST["input2"]);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if ( false===$result ) {
        die('Statement failed: '.$stmt->error);
    }
}
```

Please tell me if the above php code with prepared statement is fine or not to prevent sql injection thing. 
Also please confirm that i'm using user input as a parameter for prepared statement and not building the SQL command by joining strings together.

Comment: That looks fine, and exactly how prepared statements are supposed to be used.

Comment: "Also please confirm that i'm using user input as a parameter for prepared statement and not building the SQL command by joining strings together." - Confirmed.

Comment: While safe from SQL injection, that doesn't mean you shouldn't still vet your input variables (eg numbers should be numbers), especially as you're using $_REQUEST for values from a POSTed form (if the form is POSTed, then you should know exactly what is in $_POST and in $_GET and what might be in $_COOKIE, etc

Comment: I can't find anything on the PHP website stating that mysqli_stmt_bind_param is actually sanitizing the parameters like mysqli_real_escape does. Are you guys sure it's sanitizing the input?

Comment: It's handling escaping, and wrapping in quotes for string values.... it doesn't __sanitize__ in the sense that you could embed markup, etc in your string values.... you still need to prevent that yourself: the database doesn't know if you want `<` changing to `&lt;` etc, but `mysqli_escape_string()` doesn't sanitize either, it simply replaces quotes within the string with escaped quotes, and binding variables to a prepared statement does do that for you

Comment: You are safe from injection because you are using Parameters. The Prepare statement is actually a waste of resources in this case; you are re-preparing it each time you call submit. Prepare only works when a statement is issued on a connection and then the same statement is issued on the same connection. See e.g. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb09e986-242e-451d-a3a3-5a6c8aaf2cf6/sqlcommand-prepare-or-not-to-prepare?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: @mark-baker I am using prepared statement to insert values on database table. Let's say i have a form with "textarea". Now user can enter markup code on the "textarea" and submit the form then data are saved in the database.
I want to know what condition should i use so embed markup will be stored safely on the db and can't be harmful.

Comment: [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and it needs to be applied whether escaping strings or using bind variables because neither does this for you

Comment: i guess sanitizing is useless here since already using prepared statements, http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/should-i-use-mysqli_real_escape_string-with-prepared-statements-in-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine. Why do you wanna use $_REQUEST. It has certain vulnerabilities. Use $_POST instead. Your code is definitely cool against SQL injection